# Passing model controller to view controller in Cocoa

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

Pristine template generated by Xcode 8.2.1 for a page-based iOS application implements a model controller getter on its root view controller (snippet below). The returned model controller is used as data source for the page view controller, among other things.

It’s fairly obvious how the getter works and it makes perfect sense to only instantiate the model controller once and then reuse the instance. What’s puzzling is the comment inside the getter. It notes that **“in more complex implementations, the model controller may be passed to the view controller”**. However, it says nothing about how the passing could be done.

What are the options for passing model controller to view controller? I can only imagine a connection made via Interface Builder.

The snippet in question:

```swift
class RootViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    // ...

    var modelController: ModelController {
        // Return the model controller object, creating it if necessary.
        // In more complex implementations, the model controller may be passed to the view controller.
        if _modelController == nil {
            _modelController = ModelController()
        }
        return _modelController!
    }

    var _modelController: ModelController? = nil

    // ...
```

Comment: Your view controller could have a property of type ModelController and you would pass it from the RootViewCntroller.

Comment: @ubiAle might be a silly question, but how would I pass it?

Comment: Does this suggest I’d make an instance of `ModelController` in root controller’s `viewDidLoad()` (for example), and then assign that instance to child view controller’s `modelController` property?